# Numbered Headers have automatted headers and can not be formatted accordingly within the style

Tags: layout, numbers, tabstop

Numbered Headers have automatted headers and can not be formatted accordingly within the style.

In my case there is automatically a tabstop after 10 and is not possible to delete it within the style.

Is there any easy workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should enter a numbering with more than 10 and name the represent style accordingly. Then the attributes are taken and the not wanted tabstop is removed.